# How to get all numbers before character?

Tags: sql, regex, vertica

I need to get all rows in base that satisfy the next logic:

```
[some text/][digits(one or more)]_[some text]
```

For example,

```
'Main/Search/124_mobile'
'Main/Search/4_service'
```

Firstly I need to get these rows and then get digits before `_` symbol.

I tried this type of regex:

```
regexp_like(event, '^[Main/Search/[1-9]+(?=_')
```

But it only extracts rows like:

```
Main/Search/1_
```

and doesn't extract rows with many digits before `_` symbol

In the end, I expect to get digits before `_` symbol. For a value `'Main/Search/124_mobile'` it'll be `'124'`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @FDavidov Vertica

Comment: Didn't have the pleasure to get acquainted with it. Sorry. The only thing I can tell you is that if you are going to perform a select in which the `WHERE` includes regex's, you might need to wait for a long time for the result (here I'm assuming that your table might be quite big). I would suggest you first get a subset of the matching records (e.g. records that contain one or more digits in the particular field), and then perform a second scan using your regex expression.

Comment: @FDavidov thanks for advice! and maybe you could help me with regular expression? I think it doesn't change too much from DBMS to DBMS

Comment: Do you **always** have two `/` to separate the elements?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no, sometimes i have only one

Comment: Try `regexp_like(event, '/[0-9]+_')`. It will find all records having `/` followed with 1+ digits after which there should be a `_`. Note that `regexp_like` allows partial string matches, its pattern does not have to match the whole input.

Comment: @ChickChirik, "_it doesn't change too much from DBMS to DBMS_"... well, there are some DBMS in some versions that has no support for regex at all. Again, even if your DBMS has full support, I would suggest you be careful when using it as part of a SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is this.

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(event, '.*\/(\d+)\_.*', '\1')
```

First of all, I find with Vertica RegEx functions it is better to use `\d` (short for digits) instead of `\[0-9]` for numeric matching.

The pattern `.*\/(\d+)\_.*` matches the entire value of `event`, but because `\d+` is inclosed in parentheses, it becomes the first captured group, which is represented as backslash 1 `\1` in the replacement argument, so that even though the entire value in `event` is matched, only the first group `\1` will be shown.

To filter so that only rows that contain that pattern show up in your query results, use `REGEXP_LIKE`.

The whole query will look something like this.

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(event, '.*\/(\d+)\_.*', '\1')
FROM table
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(event, '.*\/\d+\_.*');
```

For more information see the last example (the one at the bottom about phone numbers) on this page in the documentation: https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/RegularExpressions/REGEXP_REPLACE.htm